# How to send camera feed to Python script in Unity?

Tags: unity, android, python, websocket

I have an image recognition code in Python and I need the input image to come from the Webcam in Unity. I've seen the Python [Scripting package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@7.0/manual/index.html) and the method of using a websocket and take the app as the server and the Python code as the client. And it needs to be seamless in an Android build, what method should I use and how do I get the image from Webcamtexture to Python? I'm using NumPy and the CV2 library, but I just need the data in Python in real-time.